# Bootstrapping the t-Test

Tags: r, t-test, bootstrap, resampling

my problem is of practical nature regarding bootstrapping the t-Test.

My approach is to code a function which resamples the data vector and calculates the t-statistic for each new (resampled) vector. Then I want that the type 1 error of this function converges to something around 5% by using:

```
mean(replicate(2000, my_fun(rnorm(10),...)))
```

in R (my_fun is the bootstrapped t-Test returning TRUE if alternative is rejected).
My underlying calculations of the t-Statistics are correct (I checked them manually and also tried coding them in C, C++, R).
Following problem occurs:
If I use classic non-parametric resampling such as:

```
x.sim = matrix(sample(x, replace = T, size = nboot * length(x)), nrow = nboot)
```

where `x` is the original data vector fed and `nboot` the number of resamplings, my type 1 error  is 0 (irrespective of number of simulations and resamplings), so it **never** accepts alternative hypothesis. 
However, if I change the resampling to:

```
x.sim = sample(x, replace = T, size = nboot * length(x)) * matrix(sample(c(1, -1), replace = T, size = nboot * length(x)), nrow = nboot)
```

which is basically a non-centered wild bootstrap it works and converges to 5%.

I really wonder why the original non-parametric does not work in my case. I checked other possible error sources in my codes but didn't found any. The calculations of means, variances and test statistics are correct (checked manually, correct up to e-15). So it seems that the reason is actually the resampling of the values itself and I don't get why. If you have any ideas or suggestions for improvements, please answer. :)

Also: I am aware of packages for R such as boot, however it is not my intention to use them but to understand the coding of such bootstrapping itself (e.g. for courses at university).

Edit: Here is a MWE. (Here x.sim is named x.perm)

```
  t.sim = function(x, nboot = 1000, alpha = 0.05, mu = 0){
  n = length(x)
  x.perm = matrix(sample(x, size = nboot * n, replace = T), ncol = n, nrow = nboot, byrow = T) # Resampled Bootstrap Matrix

  x.bar = rowMeans(x.perm)  # Means of Bootstrap Matrix
  x.var = (rowSums(x.perm^2) - n * x.bar^2)/(n - 1) # Variance of the bootstrap matrix
  #Bootstrapped t-statistics
  T.star = (x.bar - mu)/sqrt(x.var / n)

  #T-Value of original data
  T.true = (mean(x) - mu)/(sqrt(var(x)/n))

  #Compute Critical values
  c.crit  = quantile(T.star, c(alpha/2, 1-alpha/2))
  #Check whether the true t-Statistic lies outside those values
  perm  = (T.true < c.crit[1] | T.true > c.crit[2])
  return(perm)
}
# Check how often it returns true (thus rejects the null)
mean(replicate(1000, t.sim(rnorm(10))))
[1] 0
```

Please note that the only modification which achieved the correct convergence of type 1 error rate was the one with using rademacher weights. Different calculations in different languages didn't do the work.

Comment: p values are based on sampling distributions under the *null hypothesis*. Your approach seems to be working with sampling distributions under the alternative hypothesis.

Comment: My_fun uses mu_0 = 0 and rnorm(10) generates data points with mean = 0 and var = 1. So if you could explain where I am in the alternative and why one approach works and one not I'd be thankful. Identifying the specific problem is exactly where I'm stuck.

Comment: Clearly something is wrong with your code--but without the details of what you're doing, all we can offer is speculation.  Please include enough details to support your contention that the Type I error is zero.

Comment: Edited. Provided a MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake, it lies in the bootstrapped distribution.
In the above code the dist. is calculated by

```
T.star = (x.bar - mu)/sqrt(x.var / n)
```

Which is equal to
$$ T^{*} = \sqrt{n}\frac{\bar{X.}^{*} - \mu_0}{\hat{\sigma}^{*}} $$

However, the computation should be $$T^{*} = \sqrt{n}\frac{\bar{X.}^{*} - \mathbb{E}[\bar{X.}^{*}\mid X]}{\hat{\sigma}^{*}}$$
So, since $ \mathbb{E}[\bar{X.}^{*}\mid X] = \bar{x}$, changing my code to

```
T.star = (x.bar - mean(x))/sqrt(x.var / n)
```

does the job and convergence is reached in type-1-error rate.